# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and depends-on

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In the below code snippet

```
<bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    depends-on="environment">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT}.properties" />
```

what is the significance of "depends-on" and how to manipulate the value of ${ENVIRONMENT} ??

is the Environment referring to my system variable in the environment variables of the system?

Comment: is there any bean with name `environment` defined in the context ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-dependson)

> `depends-on` : The depends-on
>   attribute can explicitly force one or
>   more beans to be initialized before
>   the bean using this element is
>   initialized

In your case bean with id `environment` must get initialized before "placeholderProperties"